# Decomposition of LiNO3

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metal, decomposition

I have a doubt about decomposition of alkali metals.
Why does $\ce{LiNO3}$ decompose to give $\ce{Li2O}$ and $\ce{NO2}$ where as other alkali metals decompose to give corresponding nitrite and oxygen?

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_nitrate)?

> Upon thermal decomposition, $\ce{LiNO3}$ gives lithium oxide ($\ce{Li2O}$),
>   nitrogen dioxide, and oxygen:
>
> $$\ce{4 LiNO3 → 2 Li2O + 4 NO2 + O2}$$
>
> **Other group I nitrates decompose differently, forming the nitrite salt and oxygen. Because of its relatively small size, the lithium
>   cation is very polarizing, which favors the formation of the oxide.**

Answer (score 3):

You actually can get lithium nitrite from the nitrate by [controlling the decomposition temperature around 500°C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_nitrite).  But yes, as Nilay points out the nitrite is more prone to decomposing further than sodium nitrite because of the polarizing power of the lithium cation.